# autoit - cannot click a button on next web page

Tags: autoit

Noob here on AutoIt.

Im trying to click a button in which inside another page after login the website,
i've done the login website just fine, (i.e brings to the second page) then when i try to click another button (punch In button) in that page it doesn't work. need help.

this is what i did so far, my second coding doesn't seem to get the value name from the second url. point to me where did i do wrong. thanks

After it succefully login to the next page, i cannot click the button.

```
#include <IE.au3>  
Func Signin ()    
Global $oIE = _IECreate("https://just.Example.com") ;the main login webpage  

$HWND = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "hwnd")  
WinSetState($HWND, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)  
_IEAction($oIE, "visible")  
_IELoadWait($oIE)

;local refrences from html browser  
Local $username = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE,"userid")   
Local $password = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE,"pwd")

_IEFormElementSetValue ($username, "Example")  
_IEFormElementSetValue ($password, "Example")  

Local $FormAttendance = _IEFormGetObjByName($oIE, "Login") ;form actionid/name   
Local $Attendance = _IEGetObjByName($FormAttendance,"Submit",-1) ;name = submit

For $AttendanceButton In $Attendance   

If _IEFormElementGetValue($AttendanceButton) = "Attendance" Then ;value = attendance    
_IEAction($AttendanceButton, "focus")   
   Sleep(1000)   
   _IEAction($AttendanceButton, "click")   
   ExitLoop   
EndIf  
Next   

_IELoadWait($oIE)   
Next
```

This is the part where i stuck. the button is inside the 2nd url i.e on the current page.

```
local $oIE = _IEAttach($oIE,"On-Line Submission Page")    
Local $FormPunchIn = _IEFormGetObjByName($oIE, "win0") ;form action id/name         
Local $PunchIn = _IEGetObjByName($FormPunchIn,"BCS_TME_ENT_WRK_PUNCH_IN",-1)    

For $PunchInButton In $PunchIn    
If _IEFormElementGetValue($PunchInButton) = "Punch In" Then    
_IEAction($PunchInButton, "focus")    
Sleep(1000)    
_IEAction($PunchInButton, "click")
ExitLoop    
EndIf    

EndFunc
```

Help, how do i get it to click a button on the second url page?
here are the html code:

url 1 [first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yoo2.png)

url 2 [second page within current page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktElH.png)

Comment: What does the html code look like? Do you automate it for yourself? Maybe you could just use a bowser plugin like iMacros instead.

Comment: Hi Xenobiologist, thanks for your reply, im actually trying to make it easier for everyone to login instead of waiting for the IE to load and etc. i.e im planning to make a gui for it after.

Comment: It is hard to debug without direct access. Try to open the second page and then run your code from within Scite until you ve found access to the correct object.

Comment: Any guide on how to run script on an already open webpage? some guidance would be helpfull.

Comment: please help, i've tried and work around on the web, still it doesn't grab the form that i want, is there any other way?

Comment: Try to use iMacro, or post here autoitscript.com, or use AutoitWindowInfo to get the control name. Sorry, I cannot help you on that.